# why are both refigerator and refrigeration tags?

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are 5 [refrigeration](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refrigeration) questions and 77 [refrigerator](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refrigerator) questions. I can't think of anything that would really distinguish between them. Even questions about buying a fridge as opposed to what to put in the fridge don't seem so very far apart as to need separate tags. And most definitely the questions that use these tags today aren't following that pattern.

Can we make these synonyms?

Answer (score 5):

Fun fact: three questions had both tags, so only two just had refrigeration.

Anyway, maybe "refrigerators" is the right tag for equipment questions and "refrigeration" is the right tag for food storage questions, but I sure don't want to retag everything *and* push boulders up hills, so... done.

(And as for "why" - probably either because of carelessness or because someone was trying vainly to create that distinction.)

Answer (score 2):

"Will dry ice be too cold for my fesh, unfrozen steak?"

"Do fresh vegetables belong in a meat freezer?"

"Do those bowls of ice really keep milk cold enough?"

"I've been fishing for days, and finally caught the big one.  It will take me all day to sail back to Santiago.  Should I keep it in the nice cool water, or haul it up on the predator-free deck?"

I'm not saying either of you is wrong, but one could ask a question that's about refrigeration, but not refrigerators.   I guess there's a food-storage tag, though, right?

Comment: "Refrigeration" can also refer to industrial air conditioner units but that doesn't mean it makes sense in this context. We have the *[storage-method]* tag for general questions on how to store food, short-term or long-term, and it hasn't confused anybody so far - certainly a lot less confusing than trying to enforce a distinction between *refrigerators* and *refrigeration*.